# Playframework, Heroku, RabbitMQ and background workers

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

My goal is to to set up a horizontally scalable app on Heroku using the Play! framework. The web worker will receive inbound requests from users and will offload the work and run the jobs asynchronously through RabbitMQ to a background worker.

The web worker will be very light weight, however my background workers will be under a lot of load and so will need to scale.

The background workers will just be a Java class which is called from the Procfile as a command. The classes will then listen for messages published by RabbitMQ.

The challenge I'm facing is that I'm quite new to both Heroku and additionally the Play! framework.

My question is it possible/wise to build a scalable application on Heroku in this manner?

And additionally am I handling the background workers in the right approach for use within Play! framework?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The challenge I'm facing is that I'm quite new to both Heroku and additionally the Play! framework.

I can explain you how you can run your project using Play framework on Heroku. 
First you should install [Heroku toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line#download-and-install) & [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads). 
Then open your terminal and configure the git according to your account:

```
git config --global user.name "yourName"
git config --global user.email "yourgithub@email.com"
git config --global push.default matching
git config --alias.co checkout
```

Then go to your project folder and type `git init`. This is going to initialize an empty Git repository. When you commit your code, it's going to be saved in this repository, then you can push it to Github.

Once you initialize Git repository, type `git status`to see untracked files. Now you should add files to include in what will be committed: `git add .`. Dot means "all". Then you are allowed to commit them by typing: `git commit -a -m "message"`. Whenever you make some changes in your code, or add new files, you just need to type `git status`, then commit them like the way l've just explained.

After you successfully commit your code to Git repository, all you need to do is to create a repository on Github and copy the lines that are for "... or push an existing repository from the command line"
Note: You might need to set your own SSH for both Github and Heroku.

Once you upload your project to the Github, you can now set Heroku for your project. What you need to do is now set [Heroku credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line#getting-started). Then goto your project folder and type `heroku create`. Once you create heroku for your project, you can type `heroku open`to see your own heroku page for your project. `git push heroku master` allows you to push your project that you added to the Git repository to the Heroku. If everything goes well, you can refresh your browser and see that your project works on Heroku.